# check and replace only string of div with javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

```
var keyword = 'test';
var replaced = $(".test-section").html().replace(new RegExp(keyword, "igm"),'<span class="greenbackground">'+keyword+'</span>');     
$(".test-section").html(replaced);
```

I want to highlight a keyword of my paragraph. The above code is working well except, if i have `'testing'` in my `div` content, even that is getting the class. how can i make my code test only for specific string. please find the same issue on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6k2CM/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy with JavaScript's definition of a word boundary, you can use `\b`:

```
var keyword = 'test';
var replaced = $(".test-section").html().replace(new RegExp("\\b" + keyword + "\\b", "igm"),'<span class="greenbackground">'+keyword+'</span>');     
$(".test-section").html(replaced);
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6k2CM/1/)

But check [JavaScript's definition of a word character](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.2.12), it may surprise you, it's very English-centric. Specifically, it's the 26 English letters A-Z (upper or lower case), the digits 0-9, or an underscore. Anything else (`é`, for instance), is not a "word" character according to JavaScript.

> any alphanumeric character including the underscore. Equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_].

If you want to apply your own definition, you can use an alternations within capture groups to test for "beginning of line or non-word character" and "end of line or non-word character", and include the captured text (if any) in the replacement.

```
var keyword = 'test';
var replaced = $(".test-section").html().replace(new RegExp("(^|\\W)" + keyword + "($|[^\\w])", "igm"),'$1<span class="greenbackground">'+keyword+'</span>$2');     
$(".test-section").html(replaced);
```

In that example, for "your definition of a non-word character" I've used `\W`, which is JavaScript's "not a word character," but of course you'd want to adjust that (otherwise, you'd just use the `\b` solution shown earlier). Note the `$1` at the beginning of the replacement, and the `$2` at the end — those are where we put the characters we matched before and after the word (if any) back.

If you need to do a test that you can't express in a regular expression, you can use the function callback on `replace`:

```
var keyword = 'test';
var replaced = $(".test-section").html().replace(new RegExp("(^|.)" + keyword + "($|[^.])", "igm"), function(m, c1, c2) {
    // Here, c1 will be the character before your keyword, or "" at beginning of line;
    // c2 will be the character after your keyword, or "" at end of line.
    // Return the new string to replace the match with.
    // So for instance:
    if (/*...your definition says c1 and c2 are not word characters...*/) {
        // Update this occurrence:
        return c1 + '<span class="greenbackground">'+keyword+'</span>' + c2;
    } else {
        // Leave it unchanged (in effect)
        return m;
    }
});     
$(".test-section").html(replaced);
```

---

Beware "keywords" with characters in them that are special for regular expressions. Since you're using `new RegExp`, if your keyword were (say) `$span`, that would look like the end-of-line marker `$` followed by `span`.